# Using Spring Hibernate Entity to make a join between two table without relation on DB schema

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, join

I have two table whitout relation (like Foreign key) :

```
TABLE PLAN 
    PLANCODE            CHAR(8 BYTE),
    PLANDOM             VARCHAR2(20 BYTE),  
    SHORTDESCRIPTION    VARCHAR2(60 BYTE)

TABLE CASE  
    CASECODE            CHAR(20 BYTE),
    SHORTDESCRIPTION    VARCHAR2(60 BYTE), 
    DEFAULTPLANCODE     CHAR(8 BYTE)
```

PLAN.PLANCODE is unique (but could be null) and 
CASE.CASECODE is unique (but could be null)

I want to make a link between PLAN.PLANCODE and CASE.DEFAULTPLANCODE
(I could have many CASE associate to one PLAN)

I try this on my java code :
(getter and setter remove for visibility)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PLAN")
public class Plan implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Size(max = 8)
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = true)
    @Type(type = "trimmedChar")
    private String plancode;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "plancode", nullable = true, referencedColumnName="defaultplancode", updatable=false)
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    private Set<Case> case = new HashSet<>();

    @Size(max = 20)
    private String plandom;

    @Size(max = 60)
    private String shortdescription;

    ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "CASE")
public class Case implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Size(max = 20)
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    @Type(type = "trimmedChar")
    private String casecode;

    @Size(max = 60)
    private String shortdescription;

    @Size(max = 8)
    @Type(type = "trimmedChar")
    private String defaultplancode;

    ...
}
```

But when I try to launch my application, it's end with error :

> ERROR o.s.b.SpringApplication : Application startup failed
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path
>   resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]:
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NullPointerException

Could you help me ?

My finaly target is to be able to use JPA Criteria API to make some request using this entity

In "classic" SQL my requests look like this :

```
select PLAN.PLANCODE, PLAN.PLANDOM, PLAN.SHORTDESCRIPTION
from PLAN, CASE
where CASE.CASECODE = "foo"
and CASE.DEFAULTPLANCODE = PLAN.PLANCODE;
```

edit : Add the stacktrace (but not the full stacktrace because it's too long)

```
ERROR o.s.b.SpringApplication : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1054)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:829)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
    at com.orange_business.osb.Application.main(Application.java:79)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindCollectionSecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:1461)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindOneToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:865)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindStarToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:780)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder$1.secondPass(CollectionBinder.java:729)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.CollectionSecondPass.doSecondPass(CollectionSecondPass.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.originalSecondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1697)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1426)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1846)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:857)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:425)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:849)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:343)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:319)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    ... 19 common frames omitted

WARN o.s.b.SpringApplication : Error handling failed (Error creating bean with name 'delegatingApplicationListener' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cache.annotation.ProxyCachingConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importRegistry' is defined)
```

Comment: The startup error is : java.lang.NullPointerException. Could you add the stacktrace of this error to the question ?

Comment: It's exactly what the exception says. The IOC container failed to create your  `entityManagerFactory` bean because it encountered null value. can you post your XML configuration file? and the code that you try to use with that bean.

Comment: It's exactly what I think in first place, but I have other entity in my application, and the creation of the entityManagerFactory work fine until I had the code to make the join :

Comment: And if I comment the bloc code with the join, the application work fine again. I can also make some basic request on the table PLAN and CASE like select all, but of course i cannot make any request that between the 2 table with a where clause like "CASE.DEFAULTPLANCODE = PLAN.PLANCODE"